# Get ID from dataset when clicking on a series using Dimple JS

Tags: javascript, d3.js, pie-chart, dimple.js

I have a pie chart created with Dimple.js with a dataset with this structure: Id, Value, Text.

I can display the pie chart just fine.

What I can't get to work is clicking on a piece of the pie and get the Id for that piece. I need this to navigate the user to another page with this Id. How is this possible?

This is the code I have.

```
var svg = dimple.newSvg("#PieChart", "100%", "300px");
var data = [
   {"Id":1, "Value":10, "Text":"Apples"},
   {"Id":2, "Value":15, "Text":"Oranges"},
   {"Id":3, "Value":20, "Text":"Pears"}];
var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
myChart.addMeasureAxis("p", "Value");
var mySeries = myChart.addSeries("Text", dimple.plot.pie);
mySeries.addEventHandler("click", function (e) {
   alert("I want the Id.");
});
myChart.draw();
```

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hoegsdal/kaxeeoba/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any direct way.
Here is what i tried may be this can get you through

```
mySeries.addEventHandler("click", function (e) {
      var key = d3.select(e.selectedShape[0][0]).data()[0].aggField
[0];//get the text on which it is clicked
    //find the text from the data array
        var value = data.find(function(d){ return d.Text == key});
        //value has everything
    alert("I got the Id " + value.Id);
});
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/94gmoxus/)

Comment: This works assuming Text is unique. In my dataset I can't assume that is the case. It will then cause an issue in the following line of code `var mySeries = myChart.addSeries("Text", dimple.plot.pie);` as it aggregates by Text. The dataset I'm providing is already aggregated so no need for Dimple to do any aggregation. Is there any way around this issue?

Comment: Yes correct! this assumes that your text is unique. If it is not unique Dimple will aggregate it..and i dont know if there is any flag in dimple to stop it from doing that.:(

Comment: I guess D3 is the way to go with this one then.